# target_blank not working in button

Tags: html, asp.net, gridview

i want to open link in new tab how to change my code to open link in new tab

```
 <button onclick="location.href='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'," title='<%#Eval("ReportLinks")%>'> Link</button>
```

Comment: target blank should be on the anchor tag, not on the label

Answer (score 0):

Use a small `t` instead of a capital `T` for `target` like this:

```
<ItemTemplate><a href='LinkDetails.aspx?val1=total'><asp:Label ID="lblUsername" Fore-color="#1A0DAB" ToolTip="all links report" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Total") %>' target="_blank">   </a></asp:Label>
  </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Total Unique Links">
                        <ItemTemplate><a href='LinkDetails.aspx?val1=total' Target="_blank"><asp:Label ID="lblUsername" ForeColor="#1A0DAB" ToolTip="all links report" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval ("Total") %>' ></asp:Label>
                            </a>
                        </ItemTemplate>
```